# JavaFX drag and drop fails when putting multiple files into the clipboard on Java 13

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I have the following code that is designed to put a series of files from a JavaFX application into the system clipboard:

```java
pane.setOnDragDetected(event -> {

  List<File> files = ... 

  Dragboard dragBoard = ((Node)event.getSource()).startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);

  ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
  clipboardContent.putFiles(files);
  dragBoard.setContent(clipboardContent);
  event.consume();

});
```

The code works perfectly fine on Java 11 (Oracle JDK 11.0.1).

On Java 13 (OpenJDK 13.0.1) however this fails if I put **more than one file** into the clipboard (one works perfectly fine as well) with the following error message:

```
2019-11-09 23:53:28.956 java[50078:1146885] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'There are 3 items on the pasteboard, but 1 drag images. There must be 1 draggingItem per pasteboardItem.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2db3af53 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff63c00835 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2db3ada9 +[NSException raise:format:] + 189
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff2afc93bb -[NSDraggingSession(NSInternal) _initWithPasteboard:image:offset:source:] + 247
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff2afc8dee -[NSCoreDragManager dragImage:fromWindow:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:] + 1889
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff2afc867d -[NSWindow(NSDrag) dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:] + 134
    6   libglass.dylib                      0x000000012f55a618 -[GlassViewDelegate startDrag:] + 1080
    7   libglass.dylib                      0x000000012f5650c7 Java_com_sun_glass_ui_mac_MacPasteboard__1putItemsFromArray + 2439
    8   ???                                 0x00000001140bec90 0x0 + 4631293072
    9   ???                                 0x00000001140b8a90 0x0 + 4631267984
    10  ???                                 0x00000001140b8a90 0x0 + 4631267984
    11  ???                                 0x00000001140b8a90 0x0 + 4631267984
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Is this something that I can find a workaround for or have I run into an actual issue within the Java/JavaFX/macOS integration?

---

- OS: macOS Catalina (10.15.1)
- JDK: openjdk-13.0.1

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure it's not a Catalina issue *per se*, as the functionality works fine with a Java 11 runtime. It's also reproducable with a smaller dummy application so I've submitted an OpenJDK issue - let's see what comes out of this.